# Error when have 2 validation running together on form

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I have entity credit limit with 3 fields on it, which is credit rating, credit limit, and configuration, the configuration is a lookup field, credit limit field is currency and credit rating is option set(A, B, C). so when update it will validate 2 times, first is credit rating can't be same  with the credit rating that field configuration already have

Example: my pre credit rating is B, and my configuration already has 2 credit limit which is A and B, when I update the credit rating to A it suppose to be an error because configuration can't have 2 same credit rating.

and the second validation is when updating field credit limit, so current credit limit cant exceed the preimage credit limit field, my preimage credit image is $500 when I try to updating to $550 it will show error messages.

So I create 2 plugins to validate both of the condition and both of my event pipeline stage of execution is set to PreOperation.

, here is credit rating validation

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TrainingConfiguration.Plugins.Model;

namespace TrainingConfiguration.Plugins
{
    public class CreditRatingUpdateValidation : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
            if (entity.LogicalName.Contains("ita_creditlimit"))
            {

                Entity preImage = (Entity)context.PreEntityImages["CreditImage"];
                EntityReference configuration = (EntityReference)(preImage.Attributes["ita_configuration"]);
                string configurationId = configuration.Id.ToString();

                string fetchXml = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
                      <entity name='ita_creditlimit'>
                      <attribute name='ita_creditlimitid' />
                      <attribute name='ita_name' />
                      <attribute name='ita_creditrating' />
                      <attribute name='ita_configuration' />
                      <order attribute='ita_name' descending='false' />
                      <filter type='and'>                     
                      <condition attribute='ita_configuration' operator='eq' value=""{0}"" /> 
                      </filter>
                      </entity>
                      </fetch>";
                fetchXml = string.Format(fetchXml, configurationId);
                var qe = new FetchExpression(fetchXml);
                var result = service.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
                var preRating = ((OptionSetValue)preImage.Attributes["ita_creditrating"]).Value;
                var postRating = ((OptionSetValue)entity.Attributes["ita_creditrating"]).Value;
                if (result.Entities.Count > 0)
                {
                    List<String> listCreditRating = new List<string>();                        
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.Entities.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string creditRating = ((OptionSetValue)result.Entities[i].Attributes["ita_creditrating"]).Value.ToString();                           
                        listCreditRating.Add(creditRating);
                    }


                    if (postRating.ToString() != preRating.ToString())
                    {
                        bool alreadyExist = listCreditRating.Contains(postRating.ToString());
                        if (alreadyExist == true)
                        {
                            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Can't have 2 same rating");
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here for creditlimit validation

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using TrainingConfiguration.Plugins.Model;

namespace TrainingConfiguration.Plugins
{
    public class CreditUpdateValidation : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory =
            (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            if (entity.LogicalName.Equals("ita_creditlimit"))
            {
                decimal parseInt1 = 0;
                decimal parseInt2 = 0;
                Entity preImage = (Entity)context.PreEntityImages["CreditImage"];
                if (context.PreEntityImages.Contains("CreditImage"))
                {
                    Money preValue = (Money)preImage.Attributes["ita_creditlimit"];

                    parseInt1 = preValue.Value;
                }
                Money postValue = (Money)entity.Attributes["ita_creditlimit"];

                parseInt2 = postValue.Value;

                if (parseInt2 > parseInt1)
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Can't Exceed the credit limit");
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

both of the plugins work fine at first. before I try to run it together, I don't know why when I tried to
run it together it will have a strange exception, sometimes it will say the attribute ita_rating key not
found or ita_creditlimit not found even though I'm already adding it on my filtering attribute in plugin registration
I've been trying to solve this problem for a day but I still have no idea why these strange behaviors happen
because when I tried to disable one of the plugins the other plugin will work, can anyone give some enlightenment
What cause this? Is this from my code or something else ? and I already tried to use try and catch and here is the exception that I got

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
at TrainingConfiguration.Plugins.CreditUpdateValidation.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
```

Comment: and this exception only shows when 2 plugin running together

Comment: Consider using `TryGetValue` rather than `[]`.

Comment: like this var postRatings = ((OptionSetValue)entity.Attributes.TryGetValue("ita_creditrating", out); ? what the second parameter should i add , it says out object value ?

Comment: Have you registered these plugins for `create` messages too?

Comment: I would also give the `pre-images` different names. You've called them both "CreditImage" but if you've specified different attributes in either image, CRM may be getting confused

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3

Comment: @jasonscript i use different plugin to do the create messages , but the error is only shows in update.

Comment: @jasonscript or maybe i only need one plugin for update and create ? is this error caused by that ?

Comment: I was just curious because a `preimage` isn't available on CREATE messages

Comment: @mjwills hi i still don't get using TryGetValue, so TryGetValue return bool ? so how do i exactly get the attribute value from TryGetValue, can you give me litle exapmple pls, they says use trygetvalue make it 40% faster. it make me interested

Comment: `can you give me litle exapmple pls` Go to the link I provided. It is **literally** a link to `Examples`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i'm already know what is wrong here so either `Money postValue = (Money)entity.Attributes["ita_creditlimit"];` or `var value1 = (OptionSetValue)entity.Attributes["ita_creditrating"];` only have attribute when the value is change. Example when my creditlimit is $500 and i'm just leave it there not updating my creditlimit thats when the error will appears, so i fix it with try and catch, when its error i will use PreImage  for my creditlimit on catch.

Comment: `so i fix it with try and catch` `try catch` is very slow. Use `TryGetValue`.

Comment: ok so TryGetValue its just checking right wether the entity has attribute or no , and if there is  attribute we get the attribute use gett atrribute or [ ], because at first i tough TryGetValue is for  get the attribute. Am i Right  or wrong?

Comment: Wrong. It returns the value as `out`parameter.